# Why my Golang defined method not implemented implicitily while String() does

Tags: go

In https://tour.golang.org/methods/11

It states Under the hood, interface values can be thought of as a tuple of a value and a concrete type

I define M as follows

**script1**

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type I interface {
    M() string
}
type T struct {
    S string
    w string
}
func (t T) M() string {
    return "dddd"
}
func main() {
    var i I
    i = T{"Hello","eeee"}  
    fmt.Printf("(%v, %T)", i, i)    
    fmt.Println(i)
}
```

This prints out `({Hello eee}, main.T){Hello eee}`
interface i has vaule {Hello eee} and type main.T

**script2:**

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type I interface {
    M() string
}
type T struct {
    S string
    w string
}
func (t T) M() string {
    return "dddd"
}
func (t T) String() string {
    return "ccccc"
}
func main() {
    var i I
    i = T{"Hello","eeee"}
    fmt.Printf("(%v, %T)", i, i) 
    fmt.Println(i)
}
```

This prints out `(ccccc, main.T)ccccc`.

interface i has vaule ccccc and type main.T

Seems when i add String() as Stringer defined by the fmt package in script2. The String() is implemented implicitily,not sure why?

I thought in script2 i would have value "{Hello eee}" and type main.T

Comment: I don't understand the question, but [`fmt.Stringer`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Stringer) is used by the `fmt` package for printing values. See also the [Tour of Go: Stringers](https://tour.golang.org/methods/17).

Answer (score 0):

You should call `fmt.Println(i.M())` ?
Why you want `fmt` call a function while its'n exist?

A `Stringer` is a type that can describe itself as a string. The `fmt` package (and many others) look for this interface to print values

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I understand i.M() will return dddd. I expect script1 return dddd like script2 return ccccc .

Comment: @HenryXie why do you expect that?

Comment: The fmt package (and many others) look for this String() first to print values.

Answer (score 0):

Refer: https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Stringer

> Stringer is implemented by any value that has a String method, which
>   defines the “native” format for that value. The String method is used
>   to print values passed as an operand to any format that accepts a
>   string or to an unformatted printer such as Print.

In your case, in script1 you are just printing out the struct. In script2 you are providing what the builder should use when an unformatted print occurs which is a function that prints out "ccccc".